# What image formats do the major browsers support? (2012)

Tags: image, cross-browser, image-formats

I was wondering what image formats (aside from the basic JPEG, GIF, PNG) the major browsers would support, especially Chrome, Firefox, and Webkit. If anyone can provide a link to a list somewhere (that is updated frequently to cope with the frequent updates recently) that would be great. Support for other formats (like document and video) would also be nice.

I feel like this information should be listed somewhere, but I didn't find any such thing when I searched.

Comment: Are you looking for support for some particular image format?  I think all major browsers support both bitmapped and vector images of some type.  Unless you're inquiring on some particular type, staying within the scope of GIF, PNG, JPG, and SVG should never be problematic.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is a nice resource: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: Okay, if it can be put that way then I guess there must not be much support for exotic formats.

Comment: Fairly useless, as it's missing important data such as support for WebP.

Answer (score 13):

Major image file support

`.bmp`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.gif`

New

`.webp`

Comment: Jpeg2000 and webp are not working in major browsers. For webp, Google always was too dumb to simply join the standardization process to actually make it real, and then they just waste people time by making them thinking it will be the next web format. Webp and webm are used exclusively by Google internally and because of that they are supported in Chrome. No other support was done apart from that. Same for Jpeg2000, it is serious technology so if you want to use it for making website jpegs it's just overkill. If you have real jpeg2000 requirement, use javascript/flash.

Answer (score 1):

The image format supported in popular browsers: BMP, SVG, JPG, PNG and GIF. There is no two format jpeg or jpg, it's one with multiple extensions used due to [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424399/jpg-vs-jpeg-image-formats).

**Note**: SVG(Simple Vector Graphics) can produced much smaller images but allows only vector images(no raster).

Next, the other formats used are webp and jpeg2000.

Webp:- Supported by many browsers such as Chrome, Opera. There is an issue running for Firefox support [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=856375). Note that, Webp can reduce the image memory size to around 30-40% of the original size(in our experiments) on an average. This doesn't means always as sometimes we have seen transcoded webp from jpegs to go beyond the original jpeg size. The output image had no visual difference compared to original jpegs. My suggestion: serve webp where possible, i.e. Chrome, Android, Opera.

JPEG2000:- This format is great. Resizing an image does not drop quality as much as JPEG. The problem is it's too computation intensive for decoding and the fact it came over a decade ago when hardware wasn't great(especially not meant for mobile). It still is used in some cameras as it results in smaller images.

Less popular but worth mentioning: [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) and [FLIF](http://flif.info/). This will require using JS or other library to serve on web/app.

Answer (score 1):

JPEG and PNG are supported by the every browser. But the new image format which is webP is only supported by the Chrome, and partially by the Firefox and not at all supported by the Safari at all. Thou WebP is really good as it does not compromise with the quality of the image and also reduce it to 25-35% less. But we cant still use it because it is less flexible in the different browser environment.
But you can look for the other image format also which are available and compatible for each browser type.