# Accepting jpg and jpeg images through a file field

Tags: html

I've got a file field that accepts .jpg, .png and .gif images:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif">
```

I know that there's [no difference between .jpg  and .jpeg images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424399/jpg-vs-jpeg-image-formats) but Mozilla appear to advocate specifying that the file field accepts **both** [.jpg and .jpeg](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#Examples) like so:

```
<input type="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif">
```

Is this necessary?

Firefox accepts both .jpg and .jpeg when I only specify that the field accepts .jpg, but are there any browsers out there that need us to specify both?

Why do Mozilla docs show them specifying both if there's no difference?

Comment: because you're not accepting file *types*, you're accepting file *extensions*.  Different operating systems handle files differently - eg Windows just looks at the file extension and uses the defined application to open it regardless of what the actual file is.  So you need both `jpg` and `jpeg` because traditionally windows could only handle 3 letter extensions.

Comment: That's not the case anymore though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary for the server to accept it, it is necessary for the client however, when browsing for files on the clients local machine... if you don't specify `.jpeg` extension then files with that extension would be excluded from what the user can select to upload

```css
form {
  width: 600px;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
   <label for="file">With jpeg</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file"  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png"  multiple>
 </div>
</form>


<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div>
   <label for="file">Without jpeg</label>
   <input type="file" id="file" name="file" accept=".jpg, .png"  multiple>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: _if you don't specify .jpeg extension then files with that extension would be excluded from what the user can select to upload_ This is not the case with Firefox though. Which browsers does this apply to?

Comment: Try it with chrome

Comment: I've just tested with FireFox too, same behavior... are you sure you have an image with a `.jpeg` extension in the directory you're looking at

Comment: Ha, it's possibly an OS related issue. But your answer is good, I think it's best to specify both as you said.

Comment: Glad I could help